# Execute request out of phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to get some informations about request out of `phpmyadmin`. Why I'm asking this kind of questions ?

I have a software `dolibarr` which is connected to a database. I installed phpmyadmin on the same server in order to handle more easily data from database.

I would like to make export from one table which is named `llx_parts` in Excel format in order to handle data, add columns etc ... But without enter in phpmyadmin, just since dolibarr or an other software. Because my client doesn't know MySQL and phpmyadmin and could break up the database.

So he just has to click on a button and this button execute export function from phpmyadmin. This kind of things is possible ?

Thank you so much by advance !

Comment: No sense in installing `phpmyadmin` for that. Certainly you can implement a button in an html form, then use a scripting language, typically php which is already usable on your system to query the database, create a `csv` format from that and output the result to the users browser for download.

Comment: @arkascha OK, I used phpmyadmin in order to import lot of data. But as you said, it's maybe not necessary to refer one more time to phpmyadmin. I will try to write a php script with an html button which send a request to MySQL Database. I found this script : http://www.webtolosa.com/2015/06/17/exporter-une-table-mysql-au-format-csv-excel/

Comment: No. That script you referenced uses the old, outdated and long since deprecated `mysql_...()` functions. Do not use those any more. Use the current `mysqli` extension or `PDO` so that your script is portable to newer php versions.

Comment: @arkascha Ok I will look this kind of things. Thank you for help

Comment: This might be a good starting point for the query and export path: http://www.kodingmadesimple.com/2015/05/export-data-mysql-to-csv-file-php.html And obviously the really good examples in the php documentation.

Comment: Thank you ! I will look How I can insert this script inside the software and How I can add a button in order to execute this part of script ;)